# PDFsharp How to convert multiple Page TIFF to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, tiff, pdfsharp

My code is below which only converts first page. I couldn't find a way to convert all TIFF pages to PDF pages (output will be one PDF file with the same page count as TIFF file)

```
public String ConvertTiffToPdf(String LocalPath){

    PdfDocument s_document = new PdfDocument();
    int pageCount = 0;
    Image Tiff = Image.FromFile(LocalPath);
    pageCount = Tiff.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
    String Filename = Path.GetFileName(LocalPath);

    for (int a = 0; a < pageCount; a++)
    {
         PdfPage pageNew = s_document.AddPage();
         Tiff.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page,a);
         XGraphics gfxTiff = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pageNew);
         //XImage image = XImage.FromStream
         XImage image = XImage.FromStream(StreamUtils.ToStream(Tiff, ImageFormat.Tiff));
         gfxTiff.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
    }

    String SavePath = @"" + LocalPath + ".pdf";
    s_document.Save(SavePath);

    return SavePath;
}
```

Below is my StreamUtils class to convert active frame image to stream

```
public static class StreamUtils
{
    public static Stream ToStream(this Image image, ImageFormat format)
    {
        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        image.Save(stream, format);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }

}
```

Comment: @mjwills if you have the answer what is asked in question, then you would know what is lacking or wrong in my code. You wouldn't need any inputs  etc. Just try any tiff with this code and you will have the answer what you asked

Comment: Are you sure your helper routine only writes a single frame to the stream? Write to a file stream and check what you get.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the GDI build of PDFsharp, you can write `XImage image = (XImage)Tiff;` instead of creating the temporary stream (which may contain all images, not just the selected image).